# What does this error mean 'The element 'Dependent' in namespace has incomplete content

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

The element 'Dependent' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm' has incomplete content. 
List of possible elements expected: 'PropertyRef' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm'.

I'm using EF4, db first.  The error links to an association within the edmx file, unfortunately I am not very experienced with EF Database First (I have previously been using code first) however this error really does not seem to make much sense anyway.

Comment: any ideas? i have same issue with EF 6.1

Comment: Eeek, that was a while ago now!  I am guessing at - try regenerating your edmx?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing a little here but...try regenerating your edmx?